# Update Record with PDO keep getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update a row or record and I keep getting an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 11

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this I tried many things.

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "systems_requests";
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)

$sql = 'UPDATE requests SET lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lanId', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['$name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':request_description', $_POST['request_description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comDt', $_POST['comDt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
header('Location:index.php');
}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   
?>
```

revised code but still not working get error message  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 12

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "systems_requests";
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$db = 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lanId', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['$name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':request_description', $_POST['request_description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comDt', $_POST['comDt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
header('Location:index.php');
}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   




?>
```

correct code now and working

```html
<?php
 
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "systems_requests";
try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
 
$sql = 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lanId', $_POST['lanId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['$name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':department', $_POST['department'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':manager', $_POST['manager'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $_POST['request'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':request_description', $_POST['request_description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':request_comments', $_POST['request_comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':compUser', $_POST['compUser'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comDt', $_POST['comDt'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

}catch(PDOException $exception){ 
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }   

  


?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)`

Comment: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 12 and  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 12 I get these error now when I add the ;

Comment: line 12 is $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

Comment: Because PDO connection stored in `$db` variable, please make sure you understand your code

Comment: im not understanding trying to understand been going through tutorials. what do i need to change to make it work

Comment: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` <= missing semi-colon @Donny

Comment: @Fred-ii I got that put in but I still get errors as per couple comments above

Comment: See Daryl's answer, you're using the wrong variable, `$db` and `$pdo` being this line `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);` @Donny

Comment: just changed it I have a revised code above and I am still getting an error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on line 12

Comment: should I post the main page update.php I select that then it goes to update_process.php

Comment: @Donny This `$db = 'UPDATE` should be `$sql = 'UPDATE` as per Daryl's answer, did you see it?

Comment: not sure why this is off topic. I think it would help users who are starting out with PDO get a little understanding. I am not sure how to word it to be on topic and to get it of hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)

$sql = 'UPDATE requests SET lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Lets review:

This line:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)
```

is triggering the error, as PHP cannot process the next line. Solution:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

and in the comment:

> Undefined variable: pdo in C:\wamp\www\Systems\update_process.php on
>   line 12 and Call to a member function prepare()

this is because you have assigned PDO class to be `$db` in this line:

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
```

So the solution:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

**Edit:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()

This is because your SQL Query is returning false, this can happen for many many reasons. Typos in any of the query.. You are trying to call non-existant table/column names, the table does not exist. The list goes on. For debugging purposes. I would recommend changing your code to:

```
if (!stmt){
  print_r($db->errorInfo());
}
```

At the end, as it seems your try/catch isn't capturing all exceptions that are being thrown. This will show you your error and will assist in you updating your code to the query being executed correctly.

---

It also seems you have updated your question posting the new code. There are collisions with your variables:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$db = 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

What you are doing here is setting the variable `$db` to be the accessor/constructor of the PDO class, then three lines down over writing this variable to be a string. So there is no database connection in `$db`. The solution is a simple change in your variable names:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$sql= 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, lanId= :lanId, name= :name, department= :department,manager= :manager,request= :request,request_description= :request_description, request_comments= :request_comments,status= :status,comments= :comments,compUser= :compUser, compDt= :comDt WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Back to the original

Comment: Good catch on the `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);`

Comment: got it working thanks Daryl for the help and all for input I now Understand what I did wrong and I am starting to understand pdo

Answer (score 1):

there is no semicolon at the end of line 9

Comment: You should copy & paste the line in question into your answer so it's easier to identify.